# What's the difference between a @classmethod and invoking a class?

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say I have a class with two methods, one will be decorated by a classmethod and the other one will not.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_string = 'Hello'
    def test1(self):
        return self.my_string 
    @classmethod
    def test2(cls):
        return cls().my_string
```

What is the difference between these two calls:

```
MyClass().test1()
MyClass.test2()
```

I checked the elapsed time of them and they differ a lot, so it got to be different somehow, but I can't understand why. Is there a preferable way of doing it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I checked the elapsed time of them and they differ a lot"—Differ how much, in which direction, and how did you time them?

Comment: I used time.time() to wrap those calls. In the order I mentioned, these are the results
Hello
0.0009968280792236328
Hello
0.0005137920379638672

The classmethod seems to be always faster

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Doing `cls().my_string` just doesn't make any sense to me. Be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] if you haven't already, and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: That's a *tiny* difference in times; it might just be arbitrary variation. If you want to time them, use `timeit` and run each one thousands of times.

Comment: I got wondering because sometimes I want to delete the instance immediately after getting a variable that is inside of it. Thank you for welcoming me ;)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is important, but in this example, `test1` is a getter method, [which is not Pythonic](/a/36943813/4518341). Instead you would get `MyClass().my_string` directly.

Comment: With timeit they still have difference, thank you for the tip, pretty cool package

Comment: @Elger OK, I could see that making sense if the class takes some input data and processes it on initialization. This example though, doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am doing, that's why I crossed with this "problem". The input data is processed by each session of the user.

Answer (score 4):

They are very different.

`MyClass().test1()` invokes the instance method `test1` with the instance `MyClass()` as its implicit first argument (bound to the parameter `self`).

`MyClass.test2()` invokes the class method `test2` with the class `MyClass` as its implicit first argument (bound to the parameter `cls`).

You didn't ask about the more interesting `MyClass().test2()`, which still invokes the class method `test2` with the class `MyClass` (the type of the instance) as its implicit first argument.

You also didn't ask about `MyClass.test1()`, which would raise a `TypeError` because `MyClass.test1` resolves to an ordinary function, and no argument would be implicitly bound to the required parameter `self`.

---

This particular class method is strange. A class method should either be independent of any particular instance of the class, or create and *return* an instance. Creating an instance only for use in the class method doesn't really make sense.

Comment: the way you described the first and second case clarifies to me what's happening, but I can't understand why the classmethod is a bit faster yet. Thank you for the answer